# Matlab - add custom check to model advisor

Tags: matlab, customization, simulink

i want to know how i could add my simulink model advisor scripts to the modeladvisor. I already read something about a sl customization file, but i just do not know what to do.

% --- custom check

% --- names shall not start with an underscore or a number

% --- names shall not end with an underscore

model_name = input('Name of module: ', 's'); % enter module name - without ending(.slx)
%add blocks to array
blocks = find_system(model_name, 'FindAll', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'on', 'Type', 'block');

%replace all underscores/numbers at the beginning of a name with empty string
%replace all underscores at the end of a name with empty string
for i=1:length(blocks)
    set_param(blocks(i), 'Name', regexprep(get_param(blocks(i), 'Name'), '^[0-9_]+|_+$', ''));

end

I got several scripts like that.
It would be nice if someone could explain it to me/help me.
Thanks in advance!